# How do I make my modal cover the entire screen?

Tags: css, modal-dialog, width

I'm building a leaderboard web app and I'm trying to add a modal or "popup" but I can't seem to get it right.

Here's an image of what it looks like now:
As is shown, the modal does not take up the full width of the screen, resulting in the right part of the screen not being covered and the modal itself not being centered. [Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ca4mx.png)

My code looks like this:

HTML:

```
<p>{{ num_matches_in_current_season }} matches have been played in season {{ current_season }} so far.</p>
<button type="button" name="end_season_btn" id="end-season_button" class="btn btn-secondary">End Season {{ current_season }}</button>

<div class="container confirm-window" id="myConfirmWindow">
  <div class="confirm-content">
    <p>End Season {{ current_season }} after {{ num_matches_in_current_season }} matches?</p>

    <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="submit" name="end_season" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Yes. End Season {{ current_season }}">
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.confirm-window {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%x;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

/* Modal Content */
.confirm-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myConfirmWindow");

var btn = document.getElementById("end-season_button");

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

Hope some of you can help me identify the problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position property specifies the type of positioning method used for an element (static, relative, fixed, absolute or sticky).

An element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled. **The top, right, bottom, and left properties are used to position the element.**

*Source @ https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp*

With that in mind you should add the following to your `.confirm-window` class

```
.confirm-window {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

*More @ https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp regarding the position property*

Comment: Thank you for answering. The solution you proposed centered the modal on the screen however I now have an edge along both the right and the left side of the page that is not covered by the modal.

Comment: I do not have that problem on my end when reproducing your issue. If you're new to css you might have forgotten to reset the defaul browser styling behaviour. Use the following reset at the trop of your `style.css` file `*{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing: border-box;}` Here is a link to the current codepen i'm using to reproduce your issue https://codepen.io/amarinediary/pen/NWNEgJW

Comment: hmm... thanks. I'll look into that as soon as I have the time.

Comment: If this answers your problem please don't forget to vote up and accept the answer

Comment: Of course - I actually already upvotd, but it is not shown due to my low reputation.

Comment: I found the problem. The proposed solution, did the trick after I realized that I had put it into a Bootstrap container that limited the width of the div. Removing the "container" class and adding right: 0; and bottom: 0; to the css solved it. Thanks @amarinediary